# Nexus One User's Guide Printed Book?

Tags: nexus-one, documentation

Does the Nexus One come with a **printed** (i.e. real paper, not PDF) User's Guide?

Note: I know that the N1's User's Guide PDF can be downloaded from [here](http://www.google.com/googlephone/nexusone-userguide.pdf), but I would hate to use my poor printer to print 334 pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  It comes with a couple small booklets (see [this AndroidSpin post](http://forum.androidspin.com/showthread.php?t=1723) for example images) but not the full user guide.  (Also see [this HowardForums post](http://www.howardforums.com/showthread.php/1612074-Tips-and-Tricks-Thread?s=c35b453c4af9d8d9e9a909d35baabd1a&p=13438225#post13438225) answering your question).

Comment: Thanks, +1 and... ouch! (my eyes hurt staring at the screen all they long)

Comment: Might be time to invest in a decent e-reader ;) though I also prefer paper books myself.

Comment: you probably mean an **e-ink** e-reader (monochrome). Because the color nook, kobo, iPad use the same "photon bombarding technology" as my LCD screen...

Comment: Yes, exactly :)